# Were Aryans the forefathers of Hindus?

Tags: history, arya

We have been told that Aryans were living in the Indian subcontinent and that they started the caste and creed system.

Is it true that they started the Hindu belief system?

Comment: For a real answer to this question, the interested reader should visit [history.se] or some other site that is populated by actual scholars rather than by Hindu nationalists. See, for example: http://history.stackexchange.com/q/1860/2397 and http://history.stackexchange.com/q/1323/2397.

Comment: if https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Hindus:_An_Alternative_History is a work of a scholar, then I'm happy with works of Hindu nationalists.

Comment: Two problems with the question: who are aryans and who are hindus? Are you asking about correspondence between cultural and genetic relationships? The genetic identity itself is a very moot point: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_%28human_classification%29 and cultural identity is also becoming moot the last century.

Comment: Aryans: Descendants of Manu, Rishi, Devas etc. And Non-Aryans : Descendants of Adam & Eve. Btw, We believe in transcendence from any kind of duality.

Comment: see https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/26658/why-do-some-hindus-believe-no-one-ever-migrated-into-south-asia/26668#26668 and https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/27273/is-there-any-hindu-spiritual-principle-that-causes-many-hindus-to-oppose-the-ary and https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/7611/aryan-invasion-theory-evidence-for-and-against-it-in-the-vedas?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: @senshin Not everybody in this forum is a "Hindu nationalist". Please cite data to prove otherwise.

Comment: I have created a room for further discussion on this topic: https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/84439/discussion-of-vedic-homeland

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Preface: this answer is hugely lacking in details, which I hope to add later. For more detailed and evidence-based views on the matter, consider consulting the following discussions:

- [What are the latest publications demolishing the Aryan invasion/migration theory?](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/1860/what-are-the-latest-publications-demolishing-the-aryan-invasion-migration-theory) at History.SE (note: there aren't many, aside from some confusion about the genetic evidence as it currently stands)
- [Why is Dravidian history ignored?](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/1323/why-is-dravidian-history-ignored) at History.SE (tangentially-related)
- [What is the current consensus on the origins of the Brahmi script?](https://history.stackexchange.com/q/5954/2397) at History.SE (concerning the particular claim, currently thought to be false, that Brahmi derives from the Harappan script)
- [Indians - Descendants of Indo-Europeans, IVC evacuees, Dravidians, or all of the above?](http://www.reddit.com/r/AskAnthropology/comments/1gyzqq/indians_descendants_of_indoeuropeans_ivc_evacuees/caq0gtl) at /r/AskAnthropology
- ["The Aryan Migration Theory: Last Word"](http://robertlindsay.wordpress.com/2011/03/15/the-aryan-migration-theory-last-word/) on Robert Lindsay's blog (but, in particular, see the two works cited at the bottom of his post)

---

This is obviously an issue that will provoke some heated feelings, so let me just provide a brief overview of what science has to say about the migration of peoples into northern India during the Vedic period. I will update this in more detail later, but for now, this should serve as a reasonable summary.

### Linguistic evidence

Much research has been done since the 19th century to firmly establish the classification of [Indo-European languages](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indo-european_languages). We now know that Vedic Sanskrit (the language of the Rig Veda) is part of the Indo-European family of languages, and, in particular, part of [the Indo-Aryan subfamily](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indo-Aryan_languages). We have strong reason to believe that the Indo-European homeland (the "urheimat") lies near the Black Sea. This, along with other evidence, strongly suggests that the Indo-Aryan languages were brought to northern India by a migration of peoples from the northwest.

### Archaeological evidence

I am not well-acquainted with the archaeological evidence here, but it is known that there are archaeological traces of a migration towards the Indus Valley, and that at around this same time, the Indus Valley civilization collapsed. This is taken as evidence that the Indus Valley peoples were displaced by a migration of peoples from the northwest.

### Genetic evidence

The genetic evidence is less clear than the linguistic evidence. There is some Y-chromosomal evidence that the "North Indians" and the "South Indians" (Dravidians) represent two substantially different populations. This, too, suggests a migration from somewhere into northern India.

---

This evidence generally favors a scenario in which an "Aryan" population migrated into northern India c. 1500 BC. It is clear that when they migrated, they brought with them religious texts - the Vedas. In this sense, the Aryans "started" Hinduism. However, even Vedic Hinduism was not purely the creation of the Aryans - there is some evidence that some practices of the Indus Valley peoples were incorporated into what we know now as the Vedic religion.

Alternates to the Aryan migration scenario exist, but I don't know much about them, and they don't appear to have much evidence supporting them.

Comment: I don't know how presence of North indian and South Indians prove migration, many tribes with huge genetic differences live in close proximity it does not prove any migration, furthermore ivc does not show any signs of invasion.

Comment: Archaeological evidence includes: the first domestication of horses, use of the wheel for transportation, and the combination of the two into war chariots. All three of these began in the Pontic steppe and spread concurrent to the Westward expansion of Kurgan/Corded Ware culture. The predecessor of the Corded Ware culture was the Yamna culture. The Yamna culture's descendants also included the Sintashta culture and the subsequent Andronovo culture to the East.

Comment: To oversimplify, we can relate the Corded Ware culture to those Indo-Europeans who moved into Europe and the Sintasha culture to the Indo-Iranians. The Indo-Iranians later subdivided into two groups: the **Indo-Aryans**, who used Vedic Sanskrit in the Northwest region of the Indian subcontinent as well as the Mitanni-Aryans in Mesopotamia, and the **Proto-Iranians** who lived in southeastern Europe, the Iranian plateau, and remained in Central Asia. Please note, I have purposefully conflated archaeological cultures with linguistic groups for simplification for the reader.

Comment: Of further note: There were Yamna culture peoples who remained in the area rather than expaning their territory. They "became" the Srubna culture. Beyond the above referenced diffusion of horse-chariot culture & pastoralism, burial style is a large part of the archaeological analysis. However, I hesitate to discussion this as it gets very complicated and would distract from the scope of this SE.

Answer (score 22):

This is something I blogged a couple of months ago in [Quora](http://politricks.quora.com/Aryan-Invasion-and-Indus-Valley-Civilization). I'm producing it verbatim.

Since this is such a long read, *TL;DR*, No, Aryans are not the forefathers of Hindus, rather the word 'Aryan' as it's known today is an abused and prostituted word. The meaning of which has been high-jacked by racial supremacists in the 20th century Europe.

> I wanted to title this post as Aryan Invasion Theory (AIT) and the Saraswati Valley Civilization (SVC to distinguish it from Indus Valley Civilization, IVC), but I chose the former because of its popularity. The reasons will be described in the article.
>
> Indians for a long time have been given misinformation about their own origin and custom. We have been fed falsified information from both foreign media as well as local media including school text books.
>
> There is a misconception even among various Indian about the word Aryan. Aryan, which is derived from the word Arya (आर्य) in Sanskrit from which it was later hijacked by German Nationalists for their ulterior motives means 'Noble', and the place where Aryan live Āryāvarta (आर्यावर्त). It was neither a racial word nor a demonym. It was simply a word which the Sanskrit speaking people in ancient India used to call themselves.
>
> It's alleged that lighter skinned, horse riding, barbaric Aryan tribes from Central Asia (around Caucus mountain) invaded the Indus Valley Civilization in the late Harappan Period, which resulted in the Harappan people (Dravidian) to relocate deeper into the sub-continent. The nomads brought their culture (Vedic culture), their language (Sanskrit) into the subcontinent and to socially segregate native Dravidian developed caste system and put the dark skinned Dravidian into lowest Shudra caste.
>
> Let us remember that the idea that the Vedic Aryans came from outside of ancient  India and entered the region to start what became the Vedic civilization is a  foreign idea. There was never any record, either historical, textual or  archeological, that supports this premise for an Aryan invasion. There also is  no record of who would have been the invaders. The fact is that it is a theory  that came from mere linguistic speculation which happened during the nineteenth  century when very little archeological excavation had yet been done around  India. Under the aegis of Lord Macaulay, who later laid the founding stone for modern Indian education system, it was Max Müller who first came up with the AIT. In 1988 after much persuasion he finally stated,
>
> > "I have declared again and again that if I say Aryan, I mean neither blood nor  bones, nor skull nor hair; I mean simply those who speak the Aryan language...  To me, an ethnologist who speaks of Aryan blood, Aryan race, Aryan eyes and hair  is as great a sinner as a linguist who speaks of a dolichocephalic dictionary or  of brachycephalic grammar.[1](http://politricks.quora.com/Aryan-Invasion-and-Indus-Valley-Civilization)
>
> This was the same Max Muller, who used to praise Indian culture such as,
>
> > If I were asked under what sky the human mind has most fully  developed some of its choicest gifts, has most deeply pondered over the  greatest problems of life, and has found solutions of some of them which  well deserve the attention even of those who have studied Plato and Kant, I should point to India.[2](http://books.google.co.in/books/about/In_Search_of_the_Cradle_of_Civilization.html?id=Ermk_FmwcS4C&redir_esc=y)
>
> But, if we look closely with the above premise of AIT one can see the astuteness in this statement that by linking European Caucasians with Aryan, he was praising himself. Attitude of Max Muller towards Hinduism can be judged from other quotes,
>
> > The worship of Shiva, Vishnu, and other popular deities was of the same and in many cases of a more degraded and savage character than the worship of Jupiter, Apollo or Minerva.[2](http://books.google.co.in/books/about/In_Search_of_the_Cradle_of_Civilization.html?id=Ermk_FmwcS4C&redir_esc=y)
>
> and
>
> > History seems to teach that the whole human race required a gradual  education before, in the fullness of time, it could be admitted to the  truths of Christianity.[2](http://books.google.co.in/books/about/In_Search_of_the_Cradle_of_Civilization.html?id=Ermk_FmwcS4C&redir_esc=y)
>
> It is disheartening to see North and South Indians quarreling over this day in and day out. North Indians claiming themselves to be the fair skinned North Indians while the South Indians claiming to be victims of the foreigner Aryans and their caste discrimination. This has taken a toll in Indian politics we well. Tamilnadu politics is strictly anti-Hindu and anti-Brahmanic since DMK set its foot in the state politics. So let me try to clear this once and for all.
>
> I will try to enumerate why Aryan Invasion theory is a myth. Most of the items have been borrowed (copied) from various sources on the internet, and I will try to give references wherever possible.
>
> 1. The  key evidence in favor of this alleged invasion stems from the discovery  of  **skeletons** in the Indus valley towns of Harappa and Mohenjo Daro.   However, recent studies have proved that this skeleton had not resulted   from death during the war with invading Aryans and that they likely died a   natural death due to the drying up of the Saraswati river that caused   widespread famine. This is the reason why IVC should be called more aptly Saraswati Valley Civilization. Even the Vedas give much importance to River Saraswati rather than Indus. Further, the very dating of these skeletons has been   questioned (i.e. if the skeletons didn't belong to the late Indus  valley period, their death, even if due to war doesn't imply an  "invasion" of  any sort) David Feuerstein in his book "[In Search of the Cradle of Civilization](http://books.google.co.in/books/about/In_Search_of_the_Cradle_of_Civilization.html?id=Ermk_FmwcS4C&redir_esc=y)" argues there was likely a period of  "immigration" of  lighter skinned people from the area around Southern  Turkey (the  speculated homeland of Aryans) but that this immigration  happened during  the pre-ice age period and that the so called Dravidian and Aryans coexisted in  the Indian subcontinent since before the dawn of  the Indus-Saraswati  Civilization.
> 2. Various **Dravidian Gods** have  made their way into  Vedic literature and mainstream Hinduism since its  very beginnings.  Aryans, if they were "invaders" would likely have  discarded local  Dravidian gods or at the very least have denigrated/given them lower status. Shiva, known as [Pashupati](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pashupati) by Dravidians is a "Dravidian" god - he is  however given the  highest status by Vedic "Aryans" and he signifies Shakti (i.e. the  energy that keeps the Universe running). The picture below is a clay table from Harappa. Krishna, one  of the avatars of  Vishnu (as allegedly Aryan god) is well documented as  being dark skinned.
> 3. There is no evidence yet that the  **Dravidian scripts**  evolved from the as yet undecipherable Indus valley  script. In fact,  recent studies have identified similarities between  the Brahmi script and the Indus valley script. The Brahmi script was  used to write  Sanskrit before the Devnagri script came into being. This  would, in fact, imply that the Indus valley script was a precursor to  the Brahmi  script [Call Of The Lost Ages: A Study Of The Indus Valley Script](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1477504540) or Sanskrit [Indus Script Dictionary](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1450770614).
> 4. **Occam's Razor Argument**. By not using the AIT, one could  bridge one big logical gap in the history of Indic Civilization. On one hand there is the magnificent IVC which  boasted of town and urban planning and trade commerce  at a level  significantly more advanced than any other contemporary civilization - but which left behind no literary works of any sort. On  the other hand, one has the Vedas, Puranas, Upanishads - the most  ancient texts and surviving body of knowledge which make references  to events that  occurred over 7000 years ago - and yet there is no known  urban Aryan  civilization that existed around India that far back in  history. The only  logical way to fix this gap is to accept that Vedic  literature is the  product of the Indus-Saraswati civilization and that  this very civilization has been the only  common ancestor to  all modern day Indians. Another point is that before the Vedas were written, it had been an oral  tradition. However, an oral tradition of this kind of philosophy and culture  cannot be maintained by a people in constant movement for decades if not  centuries over many thousands of miles, which is what the AIT proposes. Such a tradition as the Vedic culture could be preserved only by a  sedentary people where the older generation would have the necessary time to  pass the communal lore to the younger generation.
> 5. Further, recent **[DNA studies](http://www.archaeologyonline.net/artifacts/genetics-aryan-debate.html)**  have proved  that North Indian "Aryans" and South Indian  "Dravidians" are more  genetically similar than North Indian "Aryans"  are to modern day Europeans. This bolsters the final sentences of argument 1 since it implies that the waves of Aryan migration into  India occurred in the very distant past (very likely before the Indus  valley civilization began) and that these "Aryans" and "Dravidians"  likely coexisted in the  Indian subcontinent for the last 7000 years or  more. This study also identifies that the Indian population has  been generally stable for a very long time and that there has been no  major injection of Central Asian Genes for over 10000 years at least.  So, if any migration did happen, it was long before settlements emerged,  before the domestication of the horse, before the Iron or Bronze ages. We  are talking about hunter-gatherers, small bands of nomads etc. The  latest dating of the Indus Saraswati Civilization is 9000 years - as per  Radio Metric Dating; the genetic evidence is older by this than 1000+  years at least.
> 6. **Literature**:  The Rigveda. The geographical area of the Rig Veda (RigVed) is  clearly delineated as North West India; there is no room for any doubt.  It specifically mentions the Saraswati as between the Yamuna and the  Sutlej, That can only be the Ghaggar river bed. Satellite imagery has  established that this used to be a massive river system in the old days.  The Rigveda does not mention a drying Saraswati, clearly meaning that it  must have been written well before 1900 - 2600 BC. There is no mention  of either invasion or Migration in the Rigveda; if any migration occurred,  it happened before 3000 BC - if at all. There is also no mention of a Central Asian landscape in the RigVed; it is specific in that it  mentions the Kabul river to the west and the Ganga to the east. There is  awareness of the Himalayas.
> 7. **[Radiometric Dating](http://indiawires.com/13837/news/national/indus-valley-civilization-as-old-as-7380-bc-asi/)** of the Indus-Saraswati places the real age of this civilization to somewhere around 7200 BC. This was announced by the ASI in an international  conference on 5th November 2012. This also suggests that migration did  not happen 3500 years ago, or even 9000 years ago.
> 8. The **R1a1a** gene mutation is found in North India  and East Europeans, South Siberia, Tajikistan and North Eastern Iran, A  study on this conducted in 2010 found that the oldest strain of the  R1a1a branch was concentrated in the Gujarat-Sindh-Western Rajasthan  region of India, suggesting that this was close to the origin of the  genetic group. A mutation M458 is found in Europeans but is not found  at all in Asians. This M458 mutation is at least 8000 years old, thus  lending credence to the observations above.
> 9. Another civilization at that time was the **Avestan Civilization** often known as Mesopotamian Civilization. The later formed their own religion [Zoroastrianism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zoroastrianism), which was wiped out by the Caliphate. There are striking similarities in Zoroastrianism and the Hinduism. [Ahura Mazda](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ahura_Mazda) in Zoroastrianism which is a force of Good is an Asura in Hinduism and analogically, Devas in Hinduism were [Ahirman](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Angra_Mainyu) forces of Evil in Zoroaster Religion. So, it corroborates the claim that IVC had the proto-concepts of Hinduism and it was not a concept brought by the invading Aryan hoards.
>
> So, **in my opinion, this nine-point argument against the AIT (Aryan Invasion Theory) should be sufficient to clarify any misconception about AIT and IVC**. But, the question still remains as to why this insane idea was developed in the first place, that too without any proper scientific data to validate it? The only thing which it took into account was the superficial skin color variations between south and north Indians. What motives did it serve to the Europeans?
>
> References --
>
> [[1] Max Muller, Biographies of  Words and the Home of the Aryas, by London, 1888, p. 120.](http://politricks.quora.com/Aryan-Invasion-and-Indus-Valley-Civilization)
>
> [[2] Max Müller - Wikiquote.](http://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/Max_M%C3%BCller)
>
> [[3] The Final Nail in its Coffin.](http://www.stephen-knapp.com/aryan_invasion_theory_the_final_nail_in_its_coffin.htm)
>
> [[4] Vishal Kale's answer to Politics of India: The Aryan Invasion Theory: What are the arguments given by its supporters and opponents?](http://www.quora.com/Politics-of-India-1/The-Aryan-Invasion-Theory-What-are-the-arguments-given-by-its-supporters-and-opponents/answer/Vishal-Kale-2)
>
> [[5]Shatajit Basu's answer to India: What are some alternatives to the Aryan invasion theory of Indian history?](http://www.quora.com/India/What-are-some-alternatives-to-the-Aryan-invasion-theory-of-Indian-history/answer/Shatajit-Basu)
>
> [[6] Indus Script Dictionary: S. M. Sullivan: 9781450770613: Amazon.com: Books : I had a wonderful chat with the author in the comments to this post]](http://www.archaeologyonline.net/artifacts/genetics-aryan-debate.html)

Comment: haha, I should have put a TL;DR, I guess. No, all I'm saying is the word Aryan was high-jacked by crazy racial lunatics. The word, Aryan is not a racial word.

Comment: @VineetMenon I certainly agree that the idea of the "Aryans" has been co-opted for racist purposes by terrible people, Hitler not least among them. However, are you also saying that there was not a migration of some people (whatever you want to call them) into Northern India during the Vedic period?

Comment: No, I didn't say that. What I'm saying is that the vedic culture and Hinduism is not a product of something which invaders or migrants brought. The vedas were most probably composed on the shores of Saraswati and after it dried off, they migrated to the east along the Gangatic Planes.

Comment: @VineetMenon Ah, I see. Regarding (3): [you are incorrect](http://history.stackexchange.com/q/5954/2397) per current consensus. Regarding the historical aspects of your whole post: [you are incorrect](http://history.stackexchange.com/a/1866/2397) per current consensus. Regarding (7): please clarify what exactly you are dating radiometrically (surely it isn't the river itself). Regarding (5): citation please.

Comment: @senshin, you keep taking about consensus. The people who are forming that consensus are rabidly anti-Indian leftist professors and christian missionaries living in the west. Outsiders and people with outsider's ideologies can't form consensus about insiders.

Comment: @RBK Look, I'll grant you that biases can impede a proper understanding of history (though I don't think that's a major issue here), but what you're saying here is nonsense. Indians are not in some privileged position where only they can investigate and understand the historical record. The very idea is ridiculous.

Comment: @senshin, what happened to the comment I just posted? Anyway, I just attached hyperlinks, which seemed to have been misplaced while copying.

Comment: @VineetMenon Did you post a comment? If so, I didn't see it. Perhaps you had an internet issue or something? In any case, thank you for the links; I will examine them in a little bit.

Comment: ..and what I my missing post contained was this, "The so called consensus, you are talking about also attributed the great Mauryan king as a myth before there were any archaeological evidences were excavated, only because Indian are very bad at keeping records. Indians have been very lousy at keeping memoirs and almost everything we know about Guptas and Mauryans were because of foreign travellers.

Comment: @senshin Exactly. A lot of good research about Chinese history were carried out by foreign scholars, who at that time had a much higher academic standard and capabilities than the Chinese ones... Although Chinese scholars are catching up now. Indeed, some of the foreign "researchers" now are just propagating ulterior political agendas for others and spewing nonsense, this is true, but many others are indeed serious about their work, and people can tell the difference. This site is probably just a bit way too frenzied about their nationalist-leaning ideas.

Comment: @JIXiang, Nationality or ethnicity of a scholar has no effect on his/her scholarship rather than the outlook of a person. Search for Micheal Danino, David Frawley, Stephen Knapp for western scholars who have devoted much time disproving AIT, while there are others like Paul Hacker who under the guise of being a neural scholar pushes his Christian apologetic agenda.

Answer (score 11):

The Aryan "Invasion" Theory is *disputed*.

As much as there is proof Aryan invasion, there is as much against it. See [The Aryan Invasion Theory:
The Final Nail in its Coffin](http://www.stephen-knapp.com/aryan_invasion_theory_the_final_nail_in_its_coffin.htm).

The people known as Aryans could as well been sister civilization of the Indus valley people and lived around the Saraswati river, thus many collectively call it Sindhu-Saraswati civilization(above article deals with it).

If at all Aryans came from somewhere else, it could been a "Migration" and not an Invasion" since there is no evidence for a war or conquest. There is evidence that Indus civilization collapsed due to droughts: [200-Year Drought Doomed Indus Valley Civilization](http://www.scientificamerican.com/article/200-year-drought-doomed-indus-valley-civilization/). The dates of Aryan arrival is after this drought. This makes it possible that Saraswati river also suffered drought and thus the Harappan people of the Saraswati moved into Indian mainland.

It is not easy to trace Hindu practices to one person or a group.
Indus Valley Civilization which is supposed to be pre-Aryan(considering Aryans arrived into India from somewhere) worshiped Pashupati(Shiva) and used Swastika symbols indicating **indigenous origins of Hindu practices**.

There is also a "Out of India" theory/Indigenous Aryans theory which states that, Indo-Europeans languages originated out of India & did not flow into India. Prof.[Nicholas Kanzanas](http://www.omilosmeleton.gr/en/nk_cv_en.asp) did a lot of research on this.

Comment: With all due respect, while the Aryan migration/invasion theory has not been confirmed beyond a reasonable doubt, it emphatically _is_ the current consensus theory among scholars. It is inaccurate to describe the evidence for it as equalling the evidence against it.

Comment: I am in dispute with who those so called scholars are. They are Marxist historians and European/American Indologists who hold a strong anti-Hindu bias.

Comment: And if it was the consensus, why the State of California had to mention that the theory was "disputed" in their school textbooks.

Comment: @Bharat: "And if it was the consensus, why the State of California had to mention that the theory was "disputed" in their school textbooks." The state of California added this in precisely because of pressure from Hindu groups.

Comment: @Bharat Just curious, why would Marxist/"leftist" historians hold "anti-Hindu" bias? Do they claim that Hindus treated other ethnic groups in India unfairly or something, and so the "Aryan theory" a kind of portrays Hindus as invaders and corroborates such claims? As somebody who's not familiar with Indian history, I don't understand this statement.

Comment: @JIXiang, you are right. Communism is a dishonest ideology which uses history as a tool to create a violent revolution. And to do this they need to create a binary divide between people by pitting one group against another. This is what they use Aryan theory for. Also communists have hatred for native traditions. Even in China, they went on propaganda against folk religion & Buddhism because they considered them a hindrance to spread Communism which prevented them from causing violent bloody people's revolution. Same in India.

Comment: @Bharat I'd say the situation in China is more because a lot of traditions were tied to the existing social structure, e.g. teaching the peasants to be obedient to the landlords etc., so Communism had to oppose them in order to fan the revolution. It's not that they just hate those traditions in themselves for no reason. The total destruction of Chinese tradition during cultural revolution was really more about the madness of Mao rather than a general characteristic of Communism, and things were much better during the early days of revolution. Still, I get what you said. Thanks for the reply.

Comment: @JIXiang, same in India. They link caste=class. Communism wants a classless society so destruction of class = destruction of caste = destruction of Hinduism(caste/jati is misunderstood as class). Similar to China. Every single communist in India is as mad as Mao from my experience. There is even a terrorist group called Maoists which want to replicate Chinese cultural revolution in India though violent means. The intellectuals act through distortion of history, their foot soldiers act through guns & bombs.

Comment: @JIXiang, I disagree that Communism itself is not like that. Communism is theory. What Mao, Lenin & Stalin did was Communism in practice. In theory it calls for violent revolution and dictatorship by peasants. Also Communism is irrelevant today since the % of peasants in population is very low. Many are engineers & software developers :)

Comment: @Bharat And just as an addition, I'd say I'm not against eliminating some of the bad elements from the tradition, but the problem with cultural revolution and all that is that it destroyed a lot of good aspects in the tradition but actually preserved the bad things. The folks only know how to act from what they always knew in the traditional teachings and customs. Mao didn't actually know many modern ideas,  though he was well-versed in the shenanigans of ancient Chinese emperors, so that's what he left as a model for the whole China after leaving a void by destroying the tradition.

Comment: @Bharat Yeah I definitely agree that Communism in theory is quite good, but in practice it has never quite panned out and tends to become brutal conservative regimes. Actually I think the majority of self-claimed "leftists" in the west nowadays are quite against Communism as well, e.g. Chomsky, so maybe equating communists with leftists would be a bit overly simplified :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/44956/discussion-between-bharat-and-ji-xiang).

Comment: @senshin To be clear, Bharat is correctly stating that the *Invasion Hypothesis* is no longer credible. The broader *Migration Hypothesis* is now the standard among scholars.

Answer (score 3):

The Aryan theory is trusted by Westerners on Indians. One may keep quoting un-endingly on this, the fact remains, Aryans do not exist.  If Aryans were a superior race or civilization,  there should exist a civilization older than Hinduism, the truth is - none exists better than Hindu civilization.

Request the readers to read "Holy Science" of Sri Yukteswar Giriji who is an exalted saint & yogi with divine knowledge, who explicitly denounced the Aryan theory. So do Sri Aurobindo in "In defense of Hindu Civilization".