# Aryan Migration theory—evidence for and against it in the Vedas

Tags: vedas, ancestry, arya

[Aryan Migration theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indo-Aryan_migration_theory) is a hotly contested topic. The proponents of the theory cite Vedic verses which talk of ancestors recording their memories of a cold desolate homeland and their fear of fauna like foxes therein (Central Asia) and also the importance of pole star in the their marriage rituals. They also talk of the similarities between Indo-Iranian languages and similarities between Zoroastrian and Brahmin customs and traditions—especially the similarity between the Brahmin Yagnopavita and Zoroastrian [Sudreh](http://delhiparsis.com/2007/08/19/the-sudreh-and-kusti-what-they-symbolise/) and word by word similarities between some [Zend Avestan](http://indigyan.blogspot.com/2011/04/india-in-1100-bc-atharva-veda-iranian.html) and Vedic verses.

The supporters of [Out of India theory (OIT)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indigenous_Aryans) on the other hand suggest that the presence of names of rivers like Saraswati, Ganga, Yamuna, etc in the Vedas are indicative of an early Indian ancestry.

Among the Migration theorists there are different variations—that it was a peaceful and gradual migration, like immigration and cultural diffusion; that it was violent and pushed Dravidians southward; that Aryans were nomads in Central Asia and composed the Vedas and developed high culture only after they came to India; etc.

Without dwelling into the multitude of investigative tools like genetic evidence, archaeology, linguistics, etc and **sticking only to the Vedas, where do the verses point to in terms of our ancestry?**

Comment: I recommend Edwin Bryant's book "The Quest for the Origins of Vedic Culture: The Indo-Aryan Migration Debate". It does a good job presenting both sides.

Comment: This conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/25280/discussion-on-question-by-naveen-aryan-invasion-theory-evidence-for-and-agains).

Comment: keshav srinivasan If the question is invalid, without any basis, invalid comparison or argument, still it can be continue to listed.  Learn from Yahoo / answers.com where replies to queries are NOT deleted, but maintained for others to decide. Should deletion give pleasure please do, still you have not replied to my original query of when did your ancentral premana or proof go in the context of Sri Adi Shankaracharya conducting rights to his mother. Lord Buddha given status of Vishnu avatar, without any basis any word in your literature....your website is good thought, but not your actions.

Comment: A note to editors/reviewers: People go through the contents and google for keywords before suggesting/approving edits. Out of India theory(OIT) is actual name of a theory that is antithetical to Aryan Invasion theory (AIT) and there is simply no need to change it to 'Indigenous to India' theory!!

Comment: http://news.nationalgeographic.com/news/2006/01/0110_060110_india_genes.html

Comment: @pinkpanther well, there have been migrations of scythians, huns from West but very late their comes the genetic similarity of some people from other not Aryans. Sanskrit-Vedic is Indian language. Furthermore no one has been able to find any clue for Aryan invasion in ivc.

Comment: related https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/27273/is-there-any-hindu-spiritual-principle-that-causes-many-hindus-to-oppose-the-ary and https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/26658/why-do-some-hindus-believe-no-one-ever-migrated-into-south-asia/26668#26668 and https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/11/were-aryans-the-forefathers-of-hindus/43#43

Comment: For extended discussion of this topic, please see this chat: https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/84439/discussion-of-vedic-homeland

Comment: Well, @Naveen , this has been a fool's errand. :( No one could stick only to the Vedas

Comment: Every similarity is true, except the inference. India is the root/source of all this i.e - Out **FROM** India theory, NOT Out **OF** India

Comment: Well for starters, when vásiṣṭaḥ and viśvā́mitraḥ had that big war (the RV daśa-rājan- battle) vásiṣṭaḥ called for help the párśu- tribe (Pashtuns/Persians), and other Iranian and Central Asian peoples - not the South Indians, not the vaṅga- who were living in Bengal during the time of the composition of the epics. There is a lot of complicated interlocking evidence relating to obvious facts on which RV book was oldest (RV 2, then 4), what tribes and rivers were mentioned in what book, that gives the only sensible explanation as the Aryans migrating (not invading) from Afghanistan into Punjab.

Comment: I would get into the details of that evidence, but this question is closed, and I suspect deep down very few people in this thread actually care about the answer to this question, and very few people are actually interested in the prehistory of South Asia and the study of the Aryan peoples.

Answer (score 13):

David Frawley and Michel Danino have formulated compelling arguments against the "Aryan Invasion Theory".  Dr. Frawley's book is entitled, "In Search of the Cradle of Civilization".  His collaboraters were Georg Feuerstein (a scholar regarding the history of Yoga) and Subhash Kak (a scholar researching the archaeo-astronomy of the Vedic texts).

Dr. Edwin Bryant's book (cited above) presents both sides of the debate.  During a personal email communication with me during the Spring of 2016, he did state that the current Indus Valley Civilization (whose language system is still open to debate and speculation) most likely is of Vedic origin.  This last piece of evidence would shift the debate in favor of the "OIT" theory.

The mighty Bal Gangadhar Tilak composed a book entitled, "Arctic Home in the Vedas" (published in 1903).  In this manuscript, he proposes the North Pole as the original homeland of the Aryans (during the pre-glacial period); they eventually departed from the North Pole circa 8000 BCE due to the ice deluge.  This is an interesting theoretical variation in the debate.

Traditional Acharyas and Spiritual Pillars like Dayanand Saraswati (Arya Samaj), Swami Vivekananda, Sri Aurobindo, and more recently the late Pandurang Shastri Athavale (founder of the Swadhyaya movement) have always decried the tendency of the Western historians to posit an Aryan invasion.  More recent evidence (including genetic evidence) has now shifted the debate away from an Aryan invasion.

Please visit these books to obtain a greater understanding of this fascinating debate.

EDIT:

Link to YouTube playlist: [Exploring Indian Civilization by Michel Danino, IIT Kanpur](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=10tDjMdX_nA&list=PLpLmekO2E3ZxfgHTkVMWDxnOv_lu5XEBl)

Comment: This (#1) answer isn't "sticking only to the Vedas." More proof that people just use this platform to support their preformed opinion rather than actually being open to learning and growth

Comment: @RubelliteYakṣī suggest you read the books in question.

Comment: @Haridasa The point of my comment was that when info is presented on this site from the perspective of migration theory (which people then misrepresent as the old, outdated invasion theory no longer taken seriously in academia), it gets down-voted and tossed out for not being sourced in sacred texts. But, when users agree with the sentiment of an answer, they don't actually care if it follows the rules. In other words, H.SE is so full of hypocrisy that it won't taken seriously.

Comment: @RubelliteYakṣī Sorry that is an old comment I don't care about this theory.

Comment: @Haridasa Your comment from 2 weeks ago is "old?" The comment you were replying to was 3.5 years old when you replied to it. You also say you don't care about the theory which again misses the point: the site doesn't use the same standards for all answers. I was never discussing the theories in my comment here, I was discussing how poorly the site comes across as a source of reliable information due to inconsistent use & moderation.

Comment: @RubelliteYakṣī I have changed since those few weeks.

Answer (score 6):

The Vedas are set in the framework of the geography of the Indian subcontinent. This is clearly obvious through the innumerable references to geographical features.

For example, the River Hymn (Nadi Suktam) RV 10.75 lists all the major rivers of northern India in precise order from east to west.

RV 10.75.5:

> इमं मे गङ्गे यमुने सरस्वति शुतुद्रि स्तोमं सचता परुष्ण्या । असिक्न्या मरुद्वृधे वितस्तयार्जीकीये शृणुह्या सुषोमया ॥
> O Ganga, Yamuna, Sarasvati, Shutudri, Parushni, Asikni, Marudvrdha, Vitasta, Arjikiya, Sushoma - please grace this yajna.

The river Sarasvati was also personified as a goddess and she is still with us spiritually although her physical form has dried up. The Sarasvati was the center of Vedic civilization. She is mentioned more than 70 times in the Rig Veda, whereas Ganga is mentioned 2 times.

The land between the Sarasvati and Drshadvati rivers (i.e. Kurukshetra) was considered the most sacred spot on earth, created specially by the devas themselves.

For example, RV 3.23.4:

> नि त्वा दधे वर आ पृथिव्या इळायास्पदे सुदिनत्वे अह्नाम् । दृषद्वत्यां मानुष आपयायां सरस्वत्यां रेवदग्ने दीदिहि ॥
> You, O Agni, I place on the best spot on earth, Ilāyāspada, the land on banks of the Drshadvati, Sarasvati and Āpayā.

This in itself is incontrovertible evidence of the completely indigenous origin of the Vedas and the Vedic people. There is not a single shred of evidence for a migration of the so-called Indo-European or Indo-Iranian or whatever linguistic or ethnic group from outside the Indian subcontinent.

Any invader of a new land always cherishes his original motherland and retains strong memories of it. You can see that throughout history across all geographies. For example, Babar who was originally from central Asia and invaded India and settled in India, fondly records his memories of his homeland in his autobiography Babarnama. Every Islamic invader of India maintained connections to their ancestral homeland, and regularly sent wealth usurped from India. The same pattern is seen with the British. The European Gypsies who migrated out of India more than a 1000 years ago, still retain their memories of their Indian ancestry. Against such a unanimous pattern, the Vedic people who otherwise demonstrate such a prodigious and stupendous capacity for preserving ancestral lore in excruciating detail, have not recorded a single word that indicates any origin outside the Indian subcontinent.

Since you have emphasized citing sources strictly from the Vedas, I highly recommend reading the book '**[The Rig Veda: A Historical Analysis](https://archive.org/details/the-rigveda-a-historical-analysis-shrikant-g.-talageri)**' by Shrikant Talageri.

Although I disagree with Talageri on some minute details, I completely agree with his analysis of the key aspects seen in the Rig Veda that incontrovertibly confirm a completely indigenous ancestry of the Vedic people.

Comment: Shrikant Talageri is a computer programmer who doesn't know anything about the Vedas and says stuff that just straight up make no sense. See here for 
further details on what he get wrong about the Rgveda: https://benjaminindology.wordpress.com/2020/09/13/critiquing-talageri-why-he-gets-almost-everything-wrong/

But in my opinion, my favorite error Talageri makes is claiming that Book 6 is older than Book 4. Book 6 was composed while tr̥kṣíḥ was the chieftain and Book 4 was composed while his FATHER trasádasyuḥ was chieftain, implying that tr̥kṣíḥ time-travelled to Book 6 to go be chief.

Comment: Also, the "evidence" about the Drshadvati is about as strong as arguing that because for Mormons, Utah is the most sacred place, that all the Biblical stories took place in the Great Basin of North America

Comment: I've commented this elsewhere, but the Aryans DID maintain connections to the Iranic Central Asian tribes, like the párśu- tribe (predecessors of the Parthians/Pashtuns), the álina- (the peoples of Nuristan, Afghanistan), the paṇi- too appear to be the name of a tribe (compare the name of the Parnoi the classical Greeks encountered living in what's now the Iran/Turkmenistan border area) - otherwise why would viśvā́mitraḥ, "friend of all" indeed, call upon these tribes to send their men to fight and die for him?

Answer (score 5):

> Oh Manyu with your help may we conquor both the Aryans and Dasas
>
> Oh lodra with your help may we kill both the Dasas and Aryans.”

—–Rig Veda 10-83-1

This verse pray for the destruction of both Aryans and Dasas. Should this verse be interpreted to mean that before Aryans invaded India some native ‘Aryan’ variety already existed in India and they were killed by invaded Aryans?

It is true that in many places, Rig Veda says Indra protected the Aryan color, but it also says Kanwa, the son of black. This Kanwa Rishi is said to have dark skin. Many Suktas in the 8th Mandala of Rig Veda was written by his descendants.So, these verses like Indra protecting Aryan colour should be taken as metaphorical.

Comment: Aryans is not a word to describe any specific race, it's a generic term just like biologist, engineer, doctors etc.

Comment: it's just another theory plotted by the west to confuse our already confused people.

Comment: Your answer assumes Aryan to be a genetic term, while not providing any reasoning for the same.

Comment: @IshanSingh whites believe that Aryan is a genetic term, but it's clear it's not from above verse.

Comment: @AnubhavJha It is an ethnic term, not genetic.

Comment: @Rubellite yaksi it is not an ethnic term, also there are lots of evidence against migration- why can't migration happen from India? Whole rig Veda talks about tropical flora and fauna.

Comment: @RubelliteYakṣī https://www.amrita.edu/news/myth-aryan-invasion

Comment: @RubelliteYakṣī http://indiafacts.org/propagandizing-aryan-invasion-debate-rebuttal-tony-joseph/

Comment: @Anisha That first link is arguing against old theory. It has been updated several times since then. Why continue to argue against something we already know is wrong? Argue against the latest theories. This is how science works.

Comment: @AnubhavJha "why can't migration happen from India?" I suppose it could have if human beings originated there. But it is well known that we originated in Africa.

Comment: "Should this verse be interpreted to mean that before Aryans invaded India" No. That's not how time works. The culture modern scholars call Aryan moved into Northern S. Asia, then wrote down the text.

Comment: Actually yes - again, carefully reading the Rig Veda shows that the best picture to explain all of the geographical and ethnographic data we find in the hymns of the Rig Veda samhita is that the bʰaratá tribe was one of the last tribes to enter South Asia, by the time they rolled in from Afghanistan the Aryan ánu-, druhyú-, turváśa-, yádu- and pūrú- were already there in Punjab (they came from Afghanistan earlier), then the bʰaratá- waged war against them, conquered them, and became their tribal master, and that is (ultimately) why today the country of India bears the name "Bharat".

Answer (score 4):

As a child I have seen few mythological series like the ***Ramayana* & *Mahabharata*** and have heard this word 'Arya' many times but don't think it was in context to Aryan race!

Speaking of the Aryan invasion theory, it would probably be an oversimplification to say: "Germans invented it, British used it," but not by much. The concept of the Aryans as a race and the associated idea of the 'Aryan nation' were very much a part of the ideology of German nationalism.

Before getting to the role played by German nationalism, it is useful first to take a brief look at what the word Arya does mean.

The first point to note is that the idea of the Aryans as foreigners who invaded India and destroyed the existing Harappan Civilization is a modern European invention; it receives no support whatsoever from Indian records - literary or archaeological. The same is true of the notion of the Aryans as a race; it finds no support in Indian literature or tradition. The word 'Arya' in Sanskrit means noble and never a race. In fact, the authoritative Sanskrit lexicon (c. 450 AD), the famous Amarakosa gives the following definition:

> mahakula kulinarya sabhya sajjana sadhavah

An Arya is one who hails from a noble family, of gentle behavior and demeanor, good-natured and of righteous conduct And the great epic Ramayana has a singularly eloquent expression describing Rama as:

> arya sarva samascaiva sadaiva priyadarsanah

Arya, who worked for the equality of all and was dear to everyone.

The Rigveda also uses the word Arya something like thirty six times, but never to mean a race. The nearest to a definition that one can find in the Rigveda is probably:

> praja arya jyotiragrah ... (Children of Arya are led by light)
>       RV, VII. 33.17

Julian Huxley, one of the leading biologists of the century, wrote as far back as 1939:

> In 1848 the young German scholar Friedrich Max Muller (1823-1900)
>   settled in Oxford, where he remained for the rest of his life. ...
>   About 1853 he introduced into the English language the unlucky term
>   Aryan as applied to a large group of languages. ...

As far as ancient India is concerned, one may safely say that the word Arya denoted certain spiritual and humanistic values that defined her civilization. The entire Aryan civilization - the civilization of Vedic India - was driven and sustained by these values. The whole of ancient Indian literature: from the Vedas, the Brahmanas to the Puranas to the epics like the Mahabharata and the Ramayana can be seen as a record of the struggles of an ancient people to live up to the ideals defined by these values.

Let us now take a final look at this famous theory. It was first a theory of Europe created by Europeans to free themselves from the Jewish heritage of Christianity. This was to lead to Hitler and Nazism. This theory was later transferred to India and got mixed up with the study of Sanskrit and European languages. Europeans, now calling themselves Indo-Europeans became the invading Aryas and the natives became the Dravidians. The British hired Max Muller to use this theory to turn the Vedas into an inferior scripture, to help turn educated Hindus into Christian collaborators. Max Muller used his position as a Vedic scholar to boost German nationalism by giving scriptural sanction to the German idea of the Arya race. Following German unification under Bismarck, British public and politicians became scared and anti-German. At this Max Muller, worried about his position in England, got cold feet and wriggled out of his predicament by denouncing his own former racial theory and turned it into a linguistic theory. In all of this, one would like to know where was the science?

More can be read in details [here](http://archaeologyonline.net/artifacts/aryan-invasion-history)

Found an interesting presentation ruling out rightly the so-called AIT. Watch here on [youtube](https://youtu.be/B9JbxFiLInk).

Comment: Nobility are always more closely related to each other than they are to the under-classes. They are almost always more fair-skinned as well because they do not spend the day laboring in the sun. This is the case everywhere there has even been a noble class.  

Further, there are several times in history in which the Vikings came into a new country and defeated the rulers, but then integrated themselves into the local language, culture, and religion. Why couldn't this be the case in Bharat?

Comment: @RubelliteYakṣī Because it was the other way around: The Aryans of India invaded and conquered Europe. The Puranas talk about the Pandavas and later on King Parikshit conquering Eurasia about 3000 years ago.

Comment: @Ikshvaku Please explain how domestication of the horse, invention of wheels, and development of chariots North of the Caspian Sea predate the same everywhere else in the world.

Comment: @RubelliteYakṣī Horses have been in Earth since the creation of the world. The Vedic civilization has existed since creation. We are currently in the 7th Manvantara.

Comment: @Ikshvaku The careful reader will note that I said "domestication of the horse" not "existence of the horse." Further, presupposing "Vedic civilization has existed since creation," doesn't require that it have always existed in one and only one place.

Comment: @RubelliteYakṣī Horses have been used since creation as well, according to Puranic history. Like the first kings of the Earth used it in war. While it is true the Vedic civilization existed elsewhere, it has existed in India since the beginning of this current Manvantara.

Comment: @Ikshvaku Can you please source your claims for my edification?

Comment: @RubelliteYakṣī The Manusmriti, which was spoken by the current Manu at the beginning of this Manvantara, describes the geography of India here: https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/manusmriti-with-the-commentary-of-medhatithi/d/doc145593.html

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/84437/discussion-between-rubellite-yak-and-ikshvaku).

Comment: Above comment chat aside, no one still entertains the idea of an "Aryan race." They were a cultural complex. This is a contemporary term for a historic people, not one they likely would have used for themselves as a people.

Comment: Thank you for being sensible as always Rubellite Yakṣī. Wanted to clarify two points. 1) As of 2019 it is suspected the Aryans were lighter-skinned due to the minor component of Anatolian Farmer ancestry in the Proto-Indo-European-speaking Yamnaya culture people. Light skin emerged as a mutation in Anatolia that spread with farming, the connection between sun exposure and skin color is a bit exaggerated IMO. 2) actually scholars are quite certain the adjective ā́rya- was a self-designation in the Rigvedic period, and the adjective is a vrddhi-derivative of árya- the Proto-Indo-Iranian autonym

Comment: Of course, they weren't a "race"  in any modern sense of the word, "race" is a modern understanding that developed with an ideology in Europe invented to justify the slavery and mass murder of people from Africa and native to the Americas. Back in the 2nd millennium BCE, if you understood Indo-Iranian languages, and did the sacrifices for cosmic order, congrats, you're an Aryan. The term eventually came to be a linguistic desginator. Some Achaemenid king referred to his native language as the ariya- language, and the Avestan texts abound with references to the Aryan peoples

Answer (score 1):

The problem with the historians & anthropologist is They Conclude something unidirectionally based on various available Limited incomplete samples or premises. But the work of fate is not limited to their intellect. It is not necessary that the things should work based  on limited understanding of various logists & ians, derived from limited available distorted sources. Will of lord works in various ways which historians & various -logists can't even fathom.  So scriptures are valid means of knowledge  as Brahma Sutra says & purva mimamsa proves systematically.  And Since no any historian or various -logist is omniscient enough to see past events nor were they provided with complete information (rather were provided with limited available past information in bits & pieces) they are not worthy accepted as valid means of knowledge to us. What happened some thousands years back can not be discerned by anyone scientifically. One can only speculate based on one's limited understanding what happened looking at bits & pieces But one can't gauge the pattern of the will of unfathomable  reality.

Comment: Don't make community wiki when you have no sources or when you post a long comment. They have same effect on your account when they are deleted.

Comment: @Sarvabhouma kkkkkkkkkkkkkkk

Comment: "**sticking only to the Vedas**, where do the verses point to in terms of our ancestry?"

Answer (score 0):

The astounding similarities between Greek, Latin and especially Avestan and Sanskrit strongly point to all of them being descended from a single language.  Phonetics makes it extremely unlikely that Sanskrit is the ancestral language (sanskrit has only three short vowels (a i u) and wherever Greek and latin show e Sanskrit often displays palatalization in Rig Veda - softening hard sounds like k which are preserved intact in Latin and so forth. (sanskrit chatvaras :: Latin  Quattuor)). Vedic Sanskrit and Avestan have largely replaced l by r whereas European languages keep them apart.

The only way for Aryas not to be descended from Central Asian / European migrants is for Proto Indo-European to have originated in India.  The fact that Sanskrit alone has retroflex sounds borrowed from Dravidian and loanwords from Munda, Dravidian etc. not found in European languages suggests strongly that the ancestor of Sanskrit is an immigrant to India.

Even if PIE originated in India - Vedic Sanskrit has undergone major changes from how Linguists have reconstructed PIE and it is hard to reconcile with apaurusheyatva of Sanskrit.

Comment: You are the first Hindu I have met that confirms this. In anthropology it is very clear there was migration and even the vector they approached by is pretty clear. Perhaps you can help me understand why this is such a big problem for others. Just look at the voting on this page. Clearly, people are voting with their guts and hearts, not with their heads.

Comment: @RubelliteYakṣī It was the other way around: The Aryans of India invaded and conquered Europe. The Puranas talk about the Pandavas and later on King Parikshit conquering Eurasia about 3000 years ago.

Comment: @Ikshvaku Again, please explain how Central Asian PIE artefacts predate the same kinds of artefacts in South Asia.

Comment: @RubelliteYakṣī I think it's possible they haven't found all the ancient artifacts in India.

Comment: @Ikshvaku That is an "appeal to ignorance" fallacy.

Comment: @RubelliteYakṣī What I mean is since the Puranic tradition of India mentions human civilization millions of years ago in India, it's probable that archaeologists simply haven't found old artifacts in India yet.

Comment: @Ikshvaku It is equally plausible to say that the rock next to my nightstand keeps tigers away. There's no evidence that this rock *isn't* the reason for a lack of tigers around my nightstand. That doesn't make it true, though. For more information, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argument_from_ignorance . So, we have to make a judgement about truth based on the evidence we _do_ have. For example, "We can construct a set of things which are known to keep tigers away. Rocks do not have qualities which are members of that set."

Comment: Another way to explain the fallacy is that you can use evidence to justify a claim, but you cannot use _a lack of evidence_ to justify a claim.

Comment: @RubelliteYakṣī But Archaeologists haven't scoured every nook and cranny of India and Europe, so there are still unsearched places.

Comment: Thus we must use the evidence we _have_ found, which points to the Pontic steppe as the origin of the people who later migrated to the Punjab region.

Comment: @Ikshvaku Let discuss the topic further in: https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/84439/discussion-of-vedic-homeland

Comment: I don't actually agree that there is a single 'proto' language. Even in one language we see many dialects. Just because proto-Indo European has been reconstructed, that does not mean that it actually existed as such. It's just as likely that there was an intermingling of languages by migating peoples that produced this evidence.

Comment: Agree with Mozibur Ullah and Rubellite Yakṣī. The Indo-European family "tree" looks like a tree when zoomed out over thousands of years and thousands of kilometres. But if you zoom in closer, it is a more rhizomatic structure; people learn language from each other and are doing so all the time, consciously or not. This I think is a very powerful (among many) way for language change. The Indo-European languages most likely (based on the evidence that is there) got to Spain, Britain, Iran, and India ultimately from early Indo-European language varities spoken in the Pontic-Caspian steppe.