# Who are aryan? where do they come from?

Tags: arya

Who are they? where do they come from?
What did they did and do now.
why south indians always take stand against them

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Aryan Migration theory—evidence for and against it in the Vedas](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/7611/aryan-migration-theory-evidence-for-and-against-it-in-the-vedas)

Comment: Search the forum for the word Aryan and you will get your answers.

Comment: This is off-topic question may be on-topic on [History Stack Exchange](https://history.stackexchange.com/)