# Need reference to verses or suktas vedas supporting aryans migration into Indian subcontinent

Tags: vedas

To clarify - I am not looking for answers supporting or refuting aryan migration into or out of India. I have seen [answers](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/26658/is-there-a-scriptural-basis-for-out-of-india-hypothesis/26668#26668) to similar questions. Also not looking for modern genetic or environmental theories in support or against.

I'm merely asking for contemporary evidence in form of Vedic suktas and optionally Summary of justification for the author's saying so. Avestan evidence, though may not be contemporary is also welcome.

Examples:

Nadistuti [RV 10.75](https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/rigveda/rv10075.htm) is used to speculate [here](https://www.jstor.org/stable/25196966) to be showing the aryans finally settled in Ganga region and are listing the rivers their ancestors followed.

Marut Sukta [RV 5.53](https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/rigveda/rv05053.htm) is speculated to be telling how an aryan tribe entered Indian subcontinent indirectly. The claim being one needs to be familiar with geography to write such a poem.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Aryan Migration theory—evidence for and against it in the Vedas](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/7611/aryan-migration-theory-evidence-for-and-against-it-in-the-vedas)