# Can evidence for ideas/beliefs/practices we would now call part of Hinduism be found from before the Rig Veda?

Tags: history, culture

Is there any scholarly work that argues that ideas/beliefs/practices that are part of Hinduism are from before the Rig Veda, e.g., Indus Valley Civilization?

This questiion follows up on [Were Aryans the forefathers of Hindus?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/11/were-aryans-the-forefathers-of-hindus)

Comment: The question looks unclear exactly what you're asking. Elaborate bit in body of question. Also note that historical questions like dealing with Indus Valley etc. would be more suitable on History.SE

Comment: @SK [This](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/11/were-aryans-the-forefathers-of-hindus/43#43) post shows that AIT is disputed on this site. Perhaps adding some more details regarding the treay, for example - it's period, the sides involved, the particular deities invoked and their invocations - may foster more discussion.

Comment: @SK I was replying to your comment where you had asked whether HSE subscribes to AIT. Regarding Hinduism predating Rig Veda, the very dating of the Rig Veda is disputed. I am not, however, venturing an answer to your question. Let's wait for the rest of the site.

Comment: If you think the Q belongs on HSE, you can cast a reopen vote @chhatra

Comment: Are you looking for an answer from Hindu scriptures ('Can evidence for ideas/beliefs .. be found from before the Rig Veda' implies not) or purely scholarly works? Maybe edit your question so it can be answered using scriptures? If not, simply ask, "Is there any scholarly work that argues, ideas/beliefs that are part of Hinduism were found from before the Rig Veda, e.g., Indus Valley Civilization?" and just have the 'history' & 'culture' tags on the question. You can also add a link to https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/11 and argue how your question is similar/on-topic.